# Finding a retraction of a subset of space to the Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to find a retraction from the set:

$X = \mathbb{R}_3 \setminus ((\{0,0\} \times \mathbb{R}) \cup \{(x,y,0):\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 2\})$

to the set $A$:

$A = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}_3:(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2 = 1\}$

which can be visualized as a Torus in the Z-axis.

This is the first kind of retraction that I do to a non-simple surface.

How can I build it? What geometrical elements are important in order to come up with the solution?

Comment: Shrink your space down to a ball. Now when you remove z-axis, that's like drilling a hole in that ball. That gives you a solid torus. Finally, when you remove the circle, that's like removing the central core of the solid torus, and that retracts to the torus.

Comment: You mean a subset of $3$-space, not of the plane :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nice to see the torus as a circumference rotated around the Z-axis. So basically one can think the solution of this problem in a circumference settled in the XY axis and then translate the solution.

The general solution gives a retraction of the form:

Call $u = 2(\frac{x}{||(x,y)||},\frac{y}{||(x,y)||},0)$ then:

$r(p) =  u + \frac{(x,y,z)-u}{||(x,y,z)-u||}$

And as usual the deformation is:

$H:X \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $(p,s) \mapsto (1-s)p+sr(p)$